# Not able to deploy workers on Spark-1.2.0

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-spark

I am new to spark and using spark-1.2.0 with hadoop 2.4.1. I have set up master and four slave nodes. But two of my nodes are not starting.
I have defined IP addresses of nodes in `slaves` file in spark-1.2.0/conf/ directory.

But when I try to run `./sbin/start-all.sh` the error is as follows :

```
failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker

could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker
```

This is happening for two nodes. Other two are working fine.

I've also setup `spark-env.sh` in master as well as slaves. The master also has passwordless ssh connectiviy to the slaves.

I've also tried doing `./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://IP:PORT`

It gives out the same error as before. Can someone help me with this. Where am I doing mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the solution. For all those who are starting new with spark, please check all the jar files in `lib` folder. I had `spark-assembly-1.2.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar` file missing in my slave.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue. If this is `localmode` cluster setup then you can run instead:

```
./sbin/start-master.sh
./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://localhost:7077
```

Then run:

```
MASTER=spark://localhost:7077 ./bin/pyspark
```

I was able to execute my jobs on the shell.

Do remember to setup up conf/slaves and conf/spark-env.sh as per here:
http://pulasthisupun.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-set-up-apache-spark-cluster-in.html

Also change `localhost` to your `hostname`.